# Default Magit commit state in Evil

Tags: magit, evil

I use `evil`. Normally, when I commit, I'd like to immediately start typing, but `evil` starts the buffer in `evil-normal-state`. I used to set

```
(evil-set-initial-state #'git-commit-mode 'insert)
```

But that no longer works, as Magit uses `text-mode` for its commit buffers.

How can I have Magit commits default to `evil-insert-state`?

Comment: I'm using git-commit-mode-hook and that (still) works for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a workaround:

```
(add-hook 'with-editor-mode-hook 'evil-insert-state)
```

I'm not sure why the initial state system was chosen as it either means you have a huge whitelist of states or do [lookup of derived modes](https://github.com/wasamasa/dotemacs/blob/master/init.org#initial-state), the hooks system is a much more natural fit for Evil [IMO](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues/497/regarding-initial-states).

Comment: Cool, this works perfectly!

Comment: If you are using spacemacs, which does use git-commit-mode, you can be more specific with `(add-hook 'git-commit-mode-hook 'evil-insert-state)`

Answer (score 5):

`(add-hook 'git-commit-mode-hook 'evil-insert-state)` works